# Speeding up integration by Sympy integrate

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-integration

There are two functions `expFun1` and `expFun2` that I try to integrate from t to s with respect to u.

```
import sympy as sym

# It returns a symbolic function where u is the only symbol in the function
def expFun1(X1,X2,a1,a2,T,u):        
    fx= X1*sym.exp(-a1*(T-u))+X2*sym.exp(-a2*(T-u))
    return fx

# Squared version of expFun1
def expFun2(X1,X2,a1,a2,T,u):        
    fx= (X1*sym.exp(-a1*(T-u))+X2*sym.exp(-a2*(T-u))) **2
    return fx
```

I pass the following arguments into the functions, where `u` is the only symbolised variable.

```
u = sym.symbols('u')
t=0
s=1
T=1.2
X1, X2, a1, a2= [0.5, 0.3, 2, 0.1] 

Fx1=sym.integrate(expFun1(X1,X2,a1,a2,T,u), (u,t,s))
Fx2=sym.integrate(expFun2(X1,X2,a1,a2,T,u), (u,t,s))
```

Computation time for `Fx1` is approx 0.09 seconds. However, it is approx 30 seconds for `Fx2`.
In the actual application I need to loop through different values for the non-symbolic arguments, and the integration for `expFun2` takes forever.

What would be the best way to speed up the computation time given the functional form of `expFun2`?

Comment: If you use `expand` then it will be faster. It sounds as if you are not really using symbolics optimally though if you are doing this in a loop. Just compute the general form of the integral in terms of symbols and then substitute values into it after.

Comment: Thank you Oscar for the helpful comments. I tried to implement what you have just said, would you mind looking at the code in my answer below?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant. Integration is a particularly slow operation so best not to do it inside a loop. You can make it faster still by using lambdify. That's the normal workflow with sympy: derive the general formula then use lambdify to evaluate it efficiently.

Comment: @OscarBenjamin 
I appreciate your kindness coming back to my comments! lambda function is something I need to learn from now on, the next thing in my todo list :)

Comment: Note that I said lambdify which is not the same as a lambda function

Comment: @OscarBenjamin thank you for the clarification! I totally misunderstood that point. Lots to learn...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having @Oscar Benjamin's comments, I have updated the solution as follows.

```
import sympy as sym

X1, X2, a1, a2= sym.symbols('X1, X2, a1, a2')
t,s,T,u=sym.symbols('t,s,T,u')
fx= (X1*sym.exp(-a1*(T-u))+X2*sym.exp(-a2*(T-u))) **2
fx=sym.expand(fx)    
Fx=sym.integrate(fx,(u,t,s))

ans=float(Fx.subs({X1:0.5, X2: 0.3, a1:2, a2:0.1, T:1.2, t:0, s:1}))
```